# LWC lightning-textarea dynamically change colors of words

Tags: lightning-web-components, queryselector, slds-styling-hooks

I am trying to add colors to words that starts with '@' as I am typing in js for lightning-textarea.

HTML

```
<lightning-textarea class="cssClass" name="input1" label="write"  onchange={textChange} ></lightning-textarea>
```

JS

```
@track text = '';

 textChange(event){
 this.text = event.target.value;
 }

connectedCallback() {
    this.text = this.text.split(' ').map(obj => ({ ...obj, cssClass: obj.startsWith('@') ? `<span style='color: blue'>${obj}</span>` :  `<span style='color: blue'>${obj}</span>`}))
   }

get cssClass() {
    const result  = this.text .split(' ').map(word => {
        if(word.startsWith('@') || word.startsWith('#')) {
            return `<span style='color: blue'>${word}</span>`;
        }
        return word;
    }).join(' ');
    console.log(result)
    return result
  }
```

I have tried Connected callback and getters but I am not getting any changes.

Comment: `lightning-textarea` doesn't allow formatting, so you can't color text within a `lightning-textarea` element.  Or are you trying to display this color somewhere else?

Comment: I am trying to change the color in the text area simultaneously as I am typing.

Comment: But you can't change the color of text within a lightning-textarea. As a minimum, you're going to need to use the lightning-input-rich-text

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it by creating getter to return style. I have added the code in below demo.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/xcgnlHAuUNiq8x20IqOl/src/app.js?p=stories)

Comment: That only works if the whole string starts with '@'.  I think question is trying to work out how to change the color of individual words that start with @ or #.

Comment: I can achieve that for the whole text area. I need to change the color of individual words that start with '@' or '#' as @Nick said.